# How can I read an entire forum thread in one page, minus all the noise?

Tags: forums

Sometimes there is very valuable information buried in forum threads that span hundreds of pages, like this one about the very inexpensive IPS monitors available from South Korea on [overclock.net](http://www.overclock.net/t/1232496/crossover-27q-led-led-p-27m-led-2720mdp-gold-led-monitor-club). This one example has over 500 pages.

I am looking for a way to cleaning extract all the comments into a single page (or document) to read through as quickly as possible. 
Instapaper seems to be able to go through multiple pages, but it still includes all the noise like profile info/post footers. I think a tool written specifically for forums would be required.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

For that thread in particular, you can use this link to view the first 100 posts: http://www.overclock.net/t/1232496/crossover-27q-led-led-p-27m-led-2720mdp-gold-led-monitor-club/0_100

And you can set your preferences to 100 per page, but at that it's still 54 pages.

I tried tricking it into letting me set it to 900 but it won't.

As for a permanent solution, I don't think it would be too hard to write a scraper that aggregated all the pages of a particular post, especially when the url is formatted as nicely as overclock.net (postname/0_100, postname/101_200, etc).  But I looked and couldn't find anything that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any web application that can extract a thread into a single page. I do know that this forum provides a mobile version. Which when viewed on the desktop, reduces the clutter allowing for a faster read. You can access the mobile version by clicking the mobile button on the bottom of the page.